# Random effect estimates and significant tests using lmer

Tags: lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I'm running a mixed effects model using lmer. I'm attempting to produce random effect estimates like those in the example HLM output (white background) where individual estimates and significant tests are conducted for each random effect parameter. In my R output (black background), I used lmerTest and the ranova command in an attempt to produce these random effect estimates, but I don't see an estimate for the random intercept. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Am I missing something? It looks like you have the random intercept variance estimate as the first line under random effects. I don't think you can compare to your HLM model because that has just one slope, not pre- and post-tx slopes.

Comment: What I'm trying to find/produce is the statistical significance of the random intercept estimate.

Comment: I think this question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656000/confidence-interval-of-random-effects-with-lmer

Comment: It was somewhat helpful, thank you for passing it along. On a side note, the one workaround I found was to include two random effect terms (1|SchoolID) + (PreTxSlope + Policy + PostTxSlope| StateID). Then, when I run ranova, I get significance tests for each random parameter whereas before there appeared to be no test for the random intercept.

Comment: (SchoolID) is supposed to be (StateID) above